# error; data argument not used by format string

Tags: xcode4.5

I opened iphoneMultichannelmixerTest from Apple developer's site in the new xcode upgrade. Lots of fixes, but I'm stuck with one:

> data argument not used by format string

This is it:

```
printf("BUS %%disON %lu\n", inputNum, isONValue);
```

I really don't have a clue. Can anybody help me to fix this?
(Since there appears a tiny little marker under `isONValue`, I think that might be the problem?!?)

Answer (score 0):

You have *escaped* the format option for `inputNum` by using double `%` characters.  Most likely this is what you want:

```
printf("BUS %d is ON %lu\n", inputNum, isONValue);
```

Comment: THNX!! I changed it and xcode came up with the following fix:

Comment: printf("BUS %ld isON %f\n", inputNUM, isONValue);

Comment: @user1737746 I have no idea as you haven't shown me the declaration of those variables.

Comment: well, it works, all issues have disappeared, so thnx. Since this is an apple sample code, with issues, I wanted to solve this first before using the code for my own app. I just opened this sample code for the first time and have to dive into it. I only know bus 0 en bus 1 are two multitrack audio samples.